# Arc length and area of sector

Tags: geometry

We given formula for the length of arc : $\dfrac{2\pi r \theta }{360}$ where  $\theta$ is angle subtended by an arc. Similarly, for area we have given fomula $\dfrac{\pi r^2 \theta}{360}$ where  $\theta$ is angle subtended by an arc....

But I can't understand what are the rigorous proofs of these formulas and what are the rigorous definitionss of arc length and area of a sector. Please...also give me a name of a best book which can solve my questions.(This is both reference request and a question.)

thanks...

Comment: Those formulas come from the definitions of a degree.  It was decided that there would be 360 degrees in a circle.  That's just a convention, it doesn't require rigorous proof since a degree is defined as $\frac{1}{360}$ of a full rotation around a circle.

Answer (score 2):

The formulas are valid when $\theta^\circ$ is the angle measured in degrees.

There is no rigorous proofs needed; what we need are the definitions of arc length, circumference, and area of a circle and sector: both the arc length corresponding to a subtended angle (whose vertex is the center of the circle), and the area corresponding to the resultant sector are simply fractions of the entire circle's circumference and area, respectively, equal to $\frac{\theta}{360}^{\text{th}}$ of the entire circle's circumference and area, respectively.

So, given a circle $O$ with radius $r$, we know its circumference is given by $2\pi r$. Given an angle $\theta$ measured in degrees, extended to the perimeter of the circle, then the length of the arc subtended by the angle is $\frac{\theta}{360}^{\text{th}}$ of the entire circle's circumference: $$L = \frac {\theta^\circ}{360^\circ}\cdot 2 \pi r = \frac {2 \pi r \theta^\circ}{360^\circ}$$

Likewise, given a circle $O$ with radius $r$, the area $A$ of a sector determined by $\theta$ (measured in degrees) is $\frac{\theta}{360}^{\text{th}}$ of the area of the entire circle:

$$A = \frac{\theta^\circ}{360^\circ}\cdot \pi r^2 = \frac{\pi r^2 \theta^\circ}{360^\circ}$$

See *[arc length](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_%28geometry%29)* and *[area of a sector of a circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_sector)* for explicit definitions and additional explanations and images to aid in understanding.

Less detailed are the entries in *Proof Wiki* for [area of a sector](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Area_of_Sector) and [arc length of sector](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Arc_Length_of_Sector). You'll see, they do things entirely in radians: $\theta $ is measured in radians, and so the fraction of circumference/area of a circle is given by $\dfrac{\theta}{2\pi}$ instead of $\dfrac{\theta^\circ}{360}.$

Comment: actually, i have same idea as you. But it is clear that it is not a rigor approach, I want to know what is rigor approach?? If rigor approach is not possible, THEN WHY?

Comment: Please see the links and the references there. They might help you out.

Comment: please another reference? I read wikipedia, but it is too hard for me.

Comment: But I didn't get the answer. I asked a rigor approach of formulas of arc length and sector formulas. You told me, there is no rigorous approach required. But WHY? whatever i accept answer and an upvote. But please, give answer. (and search rigor approach of formulas, Which I didn't get, with hope you can get.)

Comment: Yes, I will search on ProofWiki (they have proofs for just about everything in math!): [here is area of a sector](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Area_of_Sector) And [here is arc length of sector](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Arc_Length_of_Sector). You'll see, they do things entirely in radians ($\theta $ measured in radians, and so the fraction of circumference/area is given by $\dfrac{\theta}{2\pi}$.

Comment: @GregHill I know that, but I hope you know, the Euclidean Geometry(Modern : Neytral geometry) is really very rigorous and based with axioms and definitions. I know whatever you said, but i am interested in how mathematicians play with logic and give the rigorousness to the subject.

Comment: And perhaps i have got my answer that there must be no rigorous proof of my question. because there is no axiom in neutral geometry that explains the actual idea of angle measure using units like degrees and radians.

Comment: Is My answer can be  right. PLS, COMMENT..

Comment: But the axiom only tells us an angle measure is between 0 and 180 and nothing more. So  in the reference which you have given is both rigorous and non-rigorous, so it can't help me.

Answer (score 0):

Here are outlines of a rigorous proof without fully developing calculus.

Arc length of a circle is easy. By definition, $\pi$ is the ratio of a circle's circumference to its diameter. So $C=\pi D$. But $D=2r$. So $C=2\pi r$.

My definition, a radian is the size of the angle that subtends an arc of a circle having the same length of the circle's radius. Thus a full circle is $2\pi$ radians. A partial circle is $\theta /2\pi (2\pi r)$ where $\theta$ is measured in radians, $1$ radian $= 2\pi/360^\circ \cdot \alpha$ where $\alpha$v is the angular measure in degrees.

This can be derived from more fundamental principles, a variation of the pythagorean theorem, but it's probably best to return to this after a look at the area.

---

First consider the area of a square. We know the area of a square of side length $d$ is $d^2$, pretty much by definition. Now given a rectangle, you can ask how many squares of side length $d$ can be fit into a rectangle. Such considerations lead to an area formula for a rectangle of $A=(W/d)(L/d)d^2$. Where L is length and  W is width. It's probably better to think of one as the width/base and the other has the height though.  The $d$'s cancel, so you are left with an area expressed in the same units as $d$.

Given an arbitrary parallelogram, one can transform it into a rectangle having the same height and base using symmetry and straight edge and compass arguments.

Using similar reasoning one can transform an arbitrary triangle into a parallelogram by doubling the triangle to a parallelogram having twice the same base and height. Consequently the area of the triangle is half the area of the new parallelogram, $A=(1/2)BH$.

Planar figures made out of line segments can always be broken up into triangles, so finding their area is fairly striaght forward.

Consider a regular $n-gon$. It's highly symmetric essentially repeating an Isosceles triangle triangle every $360 /n$ degrees. The height of any of these triangles is called the apothem of the $n-gon$. The base of these triangles contributes to the perimeter, and their are $n$ of them, so $p=nB$. We have $n$ triangles with $H=a$, i.e. height is the apothem. The area of one triangle is $(1/2)HB$. So the total area is $A=(1/2)HnB=(1/2)ap$. The area of a regular $n-gon$ is half the apothem times the perimeter.

---

Now circles are curved everywhere around, but you can approximate them with regular $n-gons$. For example, you can circumscribe a circle with a triangle, a square, etc. You can also inscribe  a regular $n-gon$ into a circle using straight edge and compass for certain values of $n$.

Using trigonometry, or equivalently ratios of similar triangles, one can find the area of an inscribed polygon and demonstrate it is smaller than the circle's and that it grows with the number of sides of the ngon. One can do this as well for a circumscribed polygon, only the area is greater than the circle's and shrinks as the number of sides increases.

This lead to Archimedes' Method of Exhaustion to prove the formula for a circle, or more explicitly, the area of a circle is equal to the area of a triangle having a height equal to the radius of the circle and base equal to its circumference. Technically he didn't prove $A=\pi r^2$ he proved $A=(1/2)\cdot r \cdot (2\pi r)$. While equal in value, the distinction is important for remembering how to construct the proof.

From here, he demonstrates that the circle's area can't be greater than the triangle's without reaching a contradiction. He also demonstrates that it can't be smaller. Since it is not smaller or greater, it must be the same. This is called the trichotomy property of inequality.

This is more of a proof outline than an actual proof, but gives you the basic ideas without having to used fully developed methods of calculus. It essentially uses a limit argument to derive the formula and with more rigor than some who developed calculus centuries later.

---

A note on circumference. Similar one can show properties of the base of the inscribed and circumscribed n gons, use exhaustion on them to find the arc length ,theough ratios are probably adequate to determine that.

---

Once you know the whole, notions of proportionality can give you the parts using ratios and the definition of a radian. Give the formulas, you should be able to workout $A=(1/2)r^2 \theta $ and $C=r\theta$.

---

Texts to consult:

[Method of Exahaustion for Area of a Circle](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/%7Ecass/courses/m446-03/exhaustion.pdf)

Excellent book option: Journey Through Genius by William Dunham. It's a great book. Proofs from geometry to number theory and calculus with rich historical details. Highly recommended for proofs and their history. Also teaches you the cubic formula.