# Calculate angle, given arc length and sector area

Tags: geometry, circles

**Problem**: The length of arc of circle of radius $r$ which subtends an angle $\theta$ radians at the centre of the circle $r\theta$. The area of the sector formed by this arc and radii to either end of the arc is $\frac{1}{2}r^2\theta$. Find the angle $\theta$ if the magnitude of the arc length is $10\pi $ $cm$ and the area is $0.740\pi$ $cm^2$. (Source: Engineering Maths by Leslie Mustoe, Chapter 5, Exercise 5.1 on page 88.)

**Result**: $\frac{5\pi}{4}$ (According to the book.)

**Question**: My solution attempt yielded a very different number, and shame on me, but I do not understand what is wrong, in this seemingly simple calculation. So, could you please point out **what is wrong** in the below solution? (Please, **don't tell me the right solution**, as I want to arrive to it myself. I just want to understand where I'm making a mistake.)

**Attempt**:

$r\theta=10\pi$ $cm$  (1)

$\frac{1}{2}r^2\theta=0.74 \pi$ $cm^2$ (2)

Dividing (2) by (1):

$\frac{1}{2}r = \frac {0.74}{10}$ $cm$

$r = \frac{0.74}{5} $ $cm$ = $0.148$ $cm$.

From (1):

$\theta = \frac{10\pi}{r} = \frac{10\pi}{0.148} $

$\theta = 212.27 = 67.57 \pi$

**Similar questions**

[Arc length and area of sector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496388/arc-length-and-area-of-sector)

--> This is basically the proof for a slightly different (degree-based) version of (2).

[Find the Radius, Central Angle, and Arc Length Given Sector Area and Perimeter](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2484333/find-the-radius-central-angle-and-arc-length-given-sector-area-and-perimeter) --> The answer gives me (1) and (2).

[Central angle of a circular sector from area and arc length](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1213500/central-angle-of-a-circular-sector-from-area-and-arc-length) --> This is the same problem I have, with different numbers. Strange thing is, if I try to do it, I get the same (right) result as the OP.

Comment: Your solution seems correct to me. I put the values in a calculator and they match up as well. I am inclined to believe the book's answer is wrong... +1 for a very well asked question anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately, even in math books, sometimes answers are wrong. +1 for anyone who finds such a mistake. Then of course, math community can set it all straight.

Comment: There is something wrong with the question. Obviously, $\theta$ cannot exceed $2 \pi$. I believe the area is $40 \pi$ instead of $0.7~40\pi$.

Comment: It seems that the real problem is the arc length is given as $10\pi$ cm while the area is $0.740\text{ cm}^2$. Perhaps the area should be in $\text{m}^2$? Currently you have an arc length of about a foot and an area less than the size of a thumbnail.

Comment: Small nitpick: when you work out $\thera,$ you divide $10\pi$ cm by 0.148 cm so the result should be dimensionless (cm/cm=1). You do seem to change this in the next line

Comment: Thanks for the comments: I agree, the exercise was probably wrong. I'll correct the issue in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think that there are no doubts. Data are wrong. $\theta $ cannot be more than $2\pi$ and the picture below is the only possibility to "save" the exercise, otherwise is meaningless: a sector having perimeter $31$ cm and more CANNOT have an area of $2.3$ cm$^2$

Hope this is useful

$$...$$

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, this makes sense. However, the calculations still don't match for me. As per (1), I have $14.8\theta = 10\pi$, thus $\theta=\frac{10\pi}{14.8} = \frac{25\pi}{37}$. I get the point, though.